# ReactJS - Toggle state or property from mapped children components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to see if multiple mapped children components can be passed a function to change some of their props. The deal is that, I have a children rows that are representing shift periods, like this:

[image]

Which is actually this child component code:

```
class ShiftRow extends React.Component {
    rawMarkup() {
        var md = createRemarkable();
        var rawMarkup = md.render(this.props.children.toString());
        return { __html: rawMarkup };
    }

    handleAvailableVal = () => {
        props.onChange(event.target.checked);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            
            <tr className="shift" style={{ backgroundColor: this.props.availability ? 'green' : 'red', color: this.props.availability ? 'white' : 'black'  }}>
                {React.Children.map(this.props.children, (child, i) => {
                    // Ignore the first child
                    return child
                })}

            </tr>


        );
    }
}
```

The idea is, I want to be able to pass down initial values as the shifts are created in the parent ShiftList component, which are mapped out in the component like this:

```
if (this.props.data && this.props.data.length > 0) {
            shiftNodes = this.props.data.map(shift => (
                <ShiftRow key={shift.id} newInd={this.props.isNew} availability={shift.Available} ref={this.ShiftElement}>
                    <td>{shift.Description}</td>
                    <td style={{textAlign: 'center'}}>
                        <input
                            type="checkbox"
                            checked={shift.Available}
                            onChange={this.handleAvailableVal}
                            style={{ width: '1.5em', height: '1.5em'}}
                        />
                    </td>
                    <td style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>
                        <input readOnly
                            type="checkbox"
                            checked={shift.AllDay}
                            style={{ width: '1.5em', height: '1.5em' }}
                        />
                    </td>
                    {this.determineShiftPeriod(shift)}
                    <td>{(shift.DayOfWeek && shift.ShiftType != 'Daily') ? shift.DayOfWeek : 'N/A (Daily)'}</td>
                </ShiftRow>
            ));
        }
```

Is there a way I can change the prop in a row by row fashion like this so that I can say, pass this full set of shift represented rows to save to a database? Let me know if I can clarify anything.

Example: I want to be able to click the "Available" checkbox and watch the props value of that row update for THAT row only, and then save the row as such with other rows.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the `setState()` function (or an anonymous function that calls it) could be passed down to child components so that they can modify parent state and by so doing, modify their props indirectly. Something like this:

```js
class ParentComponent extends React.Component {
   ...
   updateState = args => this.setState(args);
   render() {
      return (<ChildComponent key={shift.id} newInd={this.props.isNew} ... updateState={() => this.updateState()}>
             </ChildComponent>);
   }
}
```

Comment: But can I pass the function to a specific row INSIDE of the child component? @Akash seemed to try to provide something I was specifically looking for, but seems there's more to the puzzle for me to figure out. And heck, I'm probably using the wrong words given my still higher amount of greenness in this field.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do this:

```
<input
 type="checkbox"
 checked={shift.Available}
 onChange={(evt) => this.handleAvailableVal({evt, shift})} // this way you'll have access to both shift and evt
 style={{ width: '1.5em', height: '1.5em'}}
/>
```

Good Luck...

Comment: Thanks a ton for your answer. Unfortunately there's more for me to figure out I guess, and this was just meant to get me started, since I got this message "this.handleAvailableVal is not a function" in the Chrome browser console

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this to modify the children item's props. Hope this helps

```js
function ANotherComponent(props) {
  console.log("props", props);
  return <div>Another component</div>;
}

function T(props) {
  const newChildren = React.Children.map(props.children, (child, i) => {
    // Ignore the first child
    return React.cloneElement(
      child,
      {
        newProps1: 1,
        newProps2: 2,
      },
      child.props.children
    );
  });
  return <div>{newChildren}</div>;
}
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <T>
        <ANotherComponent hello="1" />
        <ANotherComponent hello="1" />
        <ANotherComponent hello="1" />
        <ANotherComponent hello="1" />
        <ANotherComponent hello="1" />
      </T>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,

  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.12.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.12.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

So basically your handling of children will become something like this:

```
{React.Children.map(this.props.children, (child, i) => {
    // Ignore the first child
    return React.cloneElement(child, {
      newProps1: 1,
      newProps2: 2
    }, child.props.children)
  })}
```

Comment: Is the idea that clicking the element would change the value between 1 and 2 as a toggle? Just making sure I followed. I tried putting it in the code play pen and just see static text, probably just not putting two and two together.

Comment: Are you asking for newProp1 and newProps2 ? . These are just example. You can have your own specific props.

Comment: Ah, so you're saying I can pass the props in through that cloneElement function, and then update them indirectly via a method right inside the very element where the mapping is happening?

Comment: Yes . Just try it out then see if it is something which is expected from your side . Best way to see is just try it out

Comment: OK, I played around with it some. I noticed when using the cloneElement and putting that in my ShiftRow component, the checkbox would ONLY update if I was changing the value from an extra value I created in the ShiftRow state as the source of truth for the checkbox value. Is there a way to apply this to the mutable data all the way upstream? https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-forked-zxqs2?file=/index.js

Comment: There is too much clutter in the code right now. I was able to understand somethings and reach to this codesandbox. https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-forked-p9zx9?file=/index.js:0-9901